# size of the enclosed region in opencv python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, contour, watershed

Respected All,

I am using watershed algorithm in the attached image, now I want to find the size of the enclosed boundary image (irregular object in the image).

The image is attached:
[image]

Comment: Is your comment to Silencer code your tried and gave error? If so post in your question. See also my other comment at Silencer. Your question is now doomed to be downvoted and closed due to lack of effort..

Comment: I am using opencv3.5

Comment: That's not an answer to my question.. unless cv3.5 gives errors with below answer. Then post your trail steps and error code. Its not a problem to show your below result (comment to Silencer's answer in your question). Go edit.

Comment: @saeediqbal help me please, you can? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60978380/how-to-remove-the-background-of-the-image-of-interest-using-opencv-on-android

Answer (score 2):

Update:

In OpenCV 3.4 , `cv2.findContours` returns `image, contours, hierarchy`

```
cv2.findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]]) -> image, contours, hierarchy
```

[image]

In OpenCV 4.0, `cv2.findContours` returns `contours, hierarchy`

```
cv2.findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]]) -> contours, hierarchy
```

[image]

So to find contours in a threshed binary image, and calculate the areas, use:

```
cnts= cv.findContours(threshed, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
for cnt in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    print(area)
```

Comment: cnts = cv.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                            cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print("cnts is ",cnts)
like the above: output is following:
cnts is  (array([[255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       ..., 
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255]], dtype=uint8), [array([[[  0,   0]],

       [[  0, 131]],

       [[199, 131]],

       [[199,   0]]], dtype=int32)], array([[[-1, -1, -1, -1]]], dtype=int32))

Comment: @saeediqbal: refer with comment to your own answer.. Now its difficult to read and I've got no clue what you mean. Cheers.